# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserEmailStore'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am getting this error when I navigate to my Razor Page:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserEmailStore`1[Project.Areas.Identity.Data.MemberUser]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Project.Pages.Member.Accounts.AddModel'.

AddModel.cs:

```
public class AddModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<MemberUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<MemberUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<MemberUser> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<AddModel> _logger;

        public AddModel(UserManager<MemberUser> userManager, IUserStore<MemberUser> userStore, IUserEmailStore<MemberUser> emailStore ,ILogger<AddModel> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = emailStore;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Input.UserType != "Viewer" && Input.UserType != "Administrator")
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please select a valid user type");
                    return Page();
                }

                MemberUser newUser = CreateUser();
                newUser.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = Input.LastName;
                newUser.PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber;

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(newUser, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(newUser, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Input.UserType),
                        new Claim("MemberId", newUser.Id),
                        new Claim("FullName", $"{newUser.FirstName} {newUser.LastName}"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, newUser.Email),
                        new Claim("Username", newUser.UserName)
                    };

                    await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(newUser, claims);
                    return RedirectToPage("/Member/Accounts/Index");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
            return Page();

        }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ResourceContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ClientContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EntitiesContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<MemberUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false; // enable in production
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EntitiesContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<AgentUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false; //enable in production
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EntitiesContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AgentAccessPolicy", policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new UserTypeRequirement(new List<string> { "Agent" }));
    });

    options.AddPolicy("MemberAccessPolicy", policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new UserTypeRequirement(new List<string> { "Viewer", "Administrator" }));
    });
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AgentTypeHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MemberTypeHandler>();


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Resources")))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Resources"));
}

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Resources")),
    RequestPath = "/Resource"
});

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Why do you use both `AddIdentity` and `AddIdentityCore`?

Comment: I just found that from other source on how to add another identity.

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I add another identity?

Comment: It seems a little bit odd, since you are specifying the same user stores for them. I have never tried having different user types so can't really say what is the best approach for that.